# Obtaining minimum required go version of remote go module

Tags: go, go-modules, go-get, goinstall

Is there a way to obtain minimum required go version of remote go module?

I ran into a problem when updated all required modules to latest version that some of modules requires upper go version than mine. Is where a way to get max module version that satisfies my go version or at least check module required go version before updating it?

I have tried to search through go tools and even go sources but found nothing

Comment: For any modules where this should matter, the required go version is listed in the module's go.mod.

Comment: I don't quite get the question here? If you have a dependency that requires a more up-to-date golang version, you'll know when you try to update your dependency, you'll know. If you need that new version of the module, you'll need to update the version in your go.mod, too. It's quite simple, really.